# Extract last day of the year

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

How can I extract **last day of the current year** using the **created date** in a **calculated column**?

I need the **full date with the time**.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would happen if you:

- Calculated current Year
- Added one year (next year)
- Created a Date with january 1st of Next year
- Substracted one day

Browse all the Functions **and examples** you can work with in SharePoint and determine what functions can help you

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

- YEAR( [Created] )
- +1
- DATE( )
- -1

Answer (score 3):

December always has 31 days and it's always the 12th month.

So you can use

```
=DATE(Year(Created), 12, 31)
```